# Using -march=native flag with clang on Apple M1

Tags: macos, clang, arm64, compiler-flags, apple-m1

Whenever I try to compile using the `-march=native` flag using **clang**, I get this error:

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'
```

I'm on a Mac Mini with **M1** chip (**arm64** architecture), is there any workaround or alternative to this? Or should I just stop using this flag until it's supported?

Comment: related here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966969/why-does-march-native-not-work-on-apple-m1

Comment: I found this useful and it worked for me. Try and let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456657